# como ejecutar el evento click en las tarjetas de un juego de memoria

Tags: javascript, html, css

en el siguiente codigo:

```js
let iconos= []
let selecciones1= []
generartab()
function cargariconos(){
    iconos= [
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-chess-knight"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-hand"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-camera"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-fire-flame-curved"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-chess-queen"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-brands fa-twitch"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-scroll"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-mug-hot"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-candy-cane"></i>',
    ]
}
function generartab(){
    cargariconos();
    let selecciones1= []
    let tablero= document.getElementById("tablero");
    let tarjetas= []
    for (let i =0;  i < 24; i++) {
        tarjetas.push(`<div class="areacard" onclick="seleccionartarjeta(${i})">
        <div class="card id=card${i}">
        <div class="back" id=back${i}">
        ${iconos[0]}
            </div>
        <div class="front">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i>   
                 </div> 
             </div>
        </div>`)
        if (i%2==1){
            iconos.splice(0,1);
        }
        tarjetas.sort(()=>Math.random()-0.5)
    } tablero.innerHTML= tarjetas.join(" ");
} 
function seleccionartarjeta(i){
    let tarjeta= document.getElementById("card"+i)
    if(card.style.transform != "rotateY(180deg)"){
        card.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)"
        selecciones1.push(i)
    }
    if(selecciones1.length== 2){
        deseleccionar(selecciones1)
        selecciones1 = []
    }
}
 function deseleccionar(selecciones1) {
     setTimeout(() => {
         let trasera1= document.getElementById ("back"+ selecciones1[0])
         let trasera2= document.getElementById ("back"+ selecciones1[1])
         if(trasera1.innerHTML != trasera2.innerHTML){
            let tarjeta1= document.getElementById ("card"+ selecciones1[0])
            let tarjeta2= document.getElementById ("card"+ selecciones1[1])
            tarjeta1.style.transform= "rotateY(0deg)"
            tarjeta2.style.transform= "rotateY(0deg)"
         }
         else{
             trasera1-style.background == 'plum' 
             trasera2-style.background =='plum'
         }
     }, 1000);
 }
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
#tablero{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 25%;
}
body{
    margin: 0%;
    background: powderblue;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.card, #card{
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: iniciar 5s;
}
.card div, #card, .back{
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 80px;
    margin: 0%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
    font-size: 500%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    margin: 5px;
}
.card .front, #card{
    background: linear-gradient(orange, darkorange);
}
.card .back, #card{
    background: lightcyan;
    position: absolute;
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.nuevo-juego{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(orange, darkorange);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 35%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 47%;
}
@keyframes iniciar{
        20%, 90%{
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        0%, 100%{
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="juego2.css">
        <title>Juego de Memoria</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tablero"  onclick="seleccionartarjeta()">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="nuevo-juego" onclick="generartab()">
            Nuevo juego
        </div>
        <script src="juego2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e44160f0c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

al principio intente cambiar el evento click a otras partes del tablero pero no se ejecutaba y no se como hacer que las tarjetas den la vuelta, el evento click funciona en el boton de nuevo juego (que reinicia el memorama) pero no en las tarjetas

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, tu código no es legible en lo absoluto. Puedes acceder a este link para obtener más ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. ¡Buen viaje en esta plataforma!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No revisé tus errores de lógica, pero tienes un montón de errores de sintaxis. Corrigiéndo esos errores,se ejecuta sin problemas el evento `onclick`(que es lo que preguntas) pero aún debes revisar otros detalles que te quedan. Por favor, usa un editor de código (como `vscode`). Los errores que te señalo como los nombres de variables que no existen saltan inmediatamente.

En la función `seleccionartarjeta` pusiste `card` en lugar de `tarjeta`:

```
function seleccionartarjeta(i){
    let tarjeta= document.getElementById("card"+i)
    if(card.style.transform != "rotateY(180deg)"){
        card.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)"
        selecciones1.push(i)
    }
    ...
}
```

Cámbialo a:

```
function seleccionartarjeta(i){
    let tarjeta= document.getElementById("card"+i)
    if(tarjeta.style.transform != "rotateY(180deg)"){
        tarjeta.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)"
        selecciones1.push(i)
    }
    ...
}
```

En la función `generartab` te faltan comillas de cierre en estas líneas:

```
 <div class="card id=card${i}">
 <div class="back" id=back${i}">
```

Cámbialo a:

```
 <div class="card" id="card${i}">
 <div class="back" id="back${i}">
```

En la función  `function deseleccionar(selecciones1)` tienes guiones en lugar de puntos y tenes signos de comparación en lugar de asignación:

```
     ...
         trasera1-style.background == 'plum' 
         trasera2-style.background == 'plum'
     ...
```

Cámbialo a:

```
     ...
         trasera1.style.background = 'plum' 
         trasera2.style.background ='plum'
     ...
```

Con eso tienes una versión  funcional de tu programa.

```js
let iconos= []
let selecciones1= []
generartab()

function cargariconos(){
    iconos= [
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-chess-knight"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-hand"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-camera"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-fire-flame-curved"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-chess-queen"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-brands fa-twitch"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-scroll"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-mug-hot"></i>',
        '<i class="fa-solid fa-candy-cane"></i>',
    ]
}
function generartab(){
    cargariconos();
    let selecciones1= []
    let tablero= document.getElementById("tablero");
    let tarjetas= []
    for (let i =0;  i < 24; i++) {
        tarjetas.push(`<div class="areacard" onclick="seleccionartarjeta(${i})">
        <div class="card" id="card${i}">
        <div class="back" id="back${i}">
        ${iconos[0]}
            </div>
        <div class="front">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i>   
                 </div> 
             </div>
        </div>`)
        if (i%2==1){
            iconos.splice(0,1);
        }
        tarjetas.sort(()=>Math.random()-0.5)
    } tablero.innerHTML= tarjetas.join(" ");
} 
function seleccionartarjeta(i){
    let tarjeta= document.getElementById("card"+i)
    if(tarjeta.style.transform != "rotateY(180deg)"){
        tarjeta.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)"
        selecciones1.push(i)
    }
    if(selecciones1.length== 2){
        deseleccionar(selecciones1)
        selecciones1 = []
    }
}
 function deseleccionar(selecciones1) {
     setTimeout(() => {
         let trasera1= document.getElementById ("back"+ selecciones1[0])
         let trasera2= document.getElementById ("back"+ selecciones1[1])
         if(trasera1.innerHTML != trasera2.innerHTML){
            let tarjeta1= document.getElementById ("card"+ selecciones1[0])
            let tarjeta2= document.getElementById ("card"+ selecciones1[1])
            tarjeta1.style.transform= "rotateY(0deg)"
            tarjeta2.style.transform= "rotateY(0deg)"
         }
         else{
             trasera1.style.background = 'plum' 
             trasera2.style.background ='plum'
         }
     }, 1000);
 }
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
#tablero{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 25%;
}
body{
    margin: 0%;
    background: powderblue;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.card, #card{
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: iniciar 5s;
}
.card div, #card, .back{
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 80px;
    margin: 0%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
    font-size: 500%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    margin: 5px;
}
.card .front, #card{
    background: linear-gradient(orange, darkorange);
}
.card .back, #card{
    background: lightcyan;
    position: absolute;
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.nuevo-juego{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(orange, darkorange);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 35%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 47%;
}
@keyframes iniciar{
        20%, 90%{
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        0%, 100%{
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="juego2.css">
        <title>Juego de Memoria</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tablero"  onclick="seleccionartarjeta()">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="nuevo-juego" onclick="generartab()">
            Nuevo juego
        </div>
        <script src="juego2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e44160f0c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```